# Satellite orbit simulation in Matlab using Runge Kutta 4

Tags: mathematics, matlab, simulation, geospatial, physics

I have a satellite orbit simulation in Matlab (Using Runge Kutta 4).  It seems ugly and I don't know how to fix it.

**fx.m file:**

```
function v = fx(t,x,vx)
v = vx;
```

**fy.m file:**

```
function v = fy(t,y,vy)
v = vy;
```

**gx.m file:**

```
function v = gx(t,x,y,vx,vy)
global G M;
v = -G*M*(x/((x^2+y^2)^(3/2)));
```

**gy.m file:**

```
function v = gy(t,x,y,vx,vy)
global G M;
v = -G*M*(y/((x^2+y^2)^(3/2)));
```

**Simulation file:**

```
clear all
clc
R=6.37e6;
h=20.20e6;
global G M;
G=6.672e-11;
M=5.97e24;
vx(1)=3870 %2;
vy(1)=0;
x(1)=0;
y(1)=R+h;
t(1)=0;
dt=200;
%------
delta_T = 200;
t1 = 0;
x0 = 0;
vx0 = 3870;
y0 = R+h;
vy0 = 0;
%-----


load('topo.mat','topo','topomap1');
colormap(topomap1); 
[a,b,c]=sphere(50);  
props.AmbientStrength = 0.1;      
props.DiffuseStrength = 1;         
props.SpecularColorReflectance = .5;
props.SpecularExponent = 20;       
props.SpecularStrength = 1;       
props.FaceColor = 'texture';
props.EdgeColor = 'none';
props.FaceLighting = 'phong';
props.Cdata = topo;
surface(R.*a,R.*b,R.*c,props);
light ('position',[-1 0 1]);    
light ('position',[-1.5 0.5 -0.5],'color',[.6 .2 .2]);
view(-131,8);
%axis equal;
hold on

%-----

r=R+10^6;
hh=plot(x(1),y(1),'--rs','LineWidth',2,'MarkerEdgecolo','k','MarkerFacecolor','g', 'MarkerSize',15);
for i=0:0.05:2000

    k1 = delta_T*fx(t1,x0,vx0);
    l1 = delta_T*gx(t1,x0,y0,vx0,vy0);
    m1 = delta_T*fy(t1,y0,vy0);
    n1 = delta_T*gy(t1,x0,y0,vx0,vy0);

    k2 = delta_T*fx(t1+delta_T/2, x0+k1/2, vx0+l1/2); 
    l2 = delta_T*gx(t1+delta_T/2, x0+k1/2, y0+m1/2, vx0+l1/2, vy0+n1/2);
    m2 = delta_T*fy(t1+delta_T/2, y0+k1/2, vy0+l1/2); 
    n2 = delta_T*gy(t1+delta_T/2, x0+k1/2, y0+m1/2, vx0+l1/2, vy0+n1/2);

    k3 = delta_T*fx(t1+delta_T/2, x0+k2/2, vx0+l2/2); 
    l3 = delta_T*gx(t1+delta_T/2, x0+k2/2, y0+m2/2, vx0+l2/2, vy0+n2/2);
    m3 = delta_T*fy(t1+delta_T/2, y0+k2/2, vy0+l2/2); 
    n3 = delta_T*gy(t1+delta_T/2, x0+k2/2, y0+m2/2, vx0+l2/2, vy0+n2/2);

    k4 = delta_T*fx(t1+delta_T, x0+k3, vx0+l3); 
    l4 = delta_T*gx(t1+delta_T, x0+k3, y0+m3, vx0+l3, vy0+n3);
    m4 = delta_T*fy(t1+delta_T, y0+k3, vy0+l3); 
    n4 = delta_T*gy(t1+delta_T, x0+k3, y0+m3, vx0+l3, vy0+n3);

    x0 = x0 + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6;
    vx0 = vx0 + (l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)/6;
    y0 = y0 + (m1+2*m2+2*m3+m4)/6;
    vy0 = vy0 + (n1+2*n2+2*n3+n4)/6;

    t1 = t1 + delta_T;


    rr=sqrt(x0*x0 + y0*y0);
    aa=rr*sin(i);
    bb=rr*cos(i);
    set(hh,'XData',aa,'YData',bb);
    drawnow;
end
```